# Dynamically adding input elements on onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I want a user to click a button and a form appears. But no matter how many times they press this button a form will appear. One after each other in the order they were created. I want to achieve in JavaScript.

I am not a pro, I am teaching myself. Just wondering if I had let's say:

```
<button id="new"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"> Add New Add-on</span></button>
```

Is it possible? With what I've read I came up with this. But as I expected it doesn't work.

```
<input type="button" id="new" name="new" value="Add New Add-On" class="btn" onclick="addFields()">

<div id="New_Form"/>

</div>

<script>
    function addFields(){
        var button = document.getElementById("new").value;
        var container = document.getElementById("New_Form");
        while (New_Form.hasChildNodes()) {
            New_Form.removeChild(New_Form.lastChild);
        }
        for (i=0;i<number;i++){
            New_Form.appendChild(document.createTextNode("new " + (i+1)));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "button";
            New_Form.appendChild(input);
            New_Form.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }  
</script>
```

Comment: "and a form appears" but your code adds an input, not a "form" please clarify by rewording or edit of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Your "only" fault was that you tried to access the div wrongly. Also, "number" wasn't specified so nothing happened.

I fixed this and commented my/your code along the way. Note that I may not understood your question correctly. You're free to further ask and specify your needs.
From my point of view, this script so far is a little useless. But keep on learning!

```
<input type="button" id="new" name="new" value="Add New Add-On" class="btn" onclick="addFields()">

<div id="New_Form"/>
    <!--- Here goes the new form! -->
</div>

<script>
    function addFields(){
        // What did you want to accomplish here?
        //var button = document.getElementById("new").value;
        // You save the div with id "New_Form" into the variable container
        var container = document.getElementById("New_Form");
        // Now, why not use it then? :)
        while (container.hasChildNodes()) {
          // Removes all childs. NOTE: This will cause just one(!) form to appear in total!
            container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
        }
        // Number?? You need to specify some value here. I take 10 as an example.
        for (i=0; i < 10; i++) {
          // Again, use "container"
            container.appendChild(document.createTextNode("new " + (i+1)));
            var input = document.createElement("input");
            input.type = "button";
            container.appendChild(input);
            container.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i am going to try this. if it works i will feel extremely stupid lol. I want to be able to press the button and add as many form fields as i possibly can

Comment: Question then is, why do you iterate through all the childs of your "New_Form" div and remove them?

Comment: I didn't know how else to do it, Ive just been reading blogs and this is what they suggested. Kind of new to Javascript. The whole idea of the script is to allow users to add as many product as ons as they like. Then to style it and make the form/input into a toggle at a later date

Comment: You are aware that all the changes a user made to this *will* be gone by the time he refreshes, right? If you need to get this data persistent, you'll also need something to save the data (Database, File, ..).

Comment: Thank you. I have a database. I will save it into local storage just want to get this part correct first